# STM32 TIM2 Encoder Mode with DMA

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller, dma, stm32f4discovery

I'm working on the encoder with STM32 these days. The circuit works well with Interrupt, but I have to work with DMA. I want to count the pulse with DMA in encoder mode using the HAL library and Tim2, but I couldn't. I'd appreciate it if you could help me. Have a nice day.
Method I use: HAL_TIM_Encoder_Start_DMA (&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3, (int32_t*)pdC1, (int32_t*)pdC2, 1);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvDQj.png)

Comment: Does your MCU timers support encoder mode ? If yes, set some break points and verify that your locals are as expected and that your registers are as you expect according to the data sheet.

Comment: Yeap, my MCU timer(TIM2) support encoder mode. I am using pooling method to read TIM2 counter value. But I want to read with DMA.